# NetSuite API search by externalId

Tags: netsuite

I am attempting to search for a NetSuite Vendor (which may or may not exist in NetSuite) with the NetSuite API; however, the only piece of information I have about the Vendor is the externalId.  My goal is to query NetSuite for the Vendor with the given externalId and if the Vendor exists, use it in a subsequent API call.  If the Vendor doesn't exist, I'll create it and use the vendor I've just created in the subsequent API call.
Despite my searches I have not been able to find a way to search NetSuite for a record by externalId (I've found many ways to search by a Field; however I haven't found a way to search by an Attribute i.e. externalId). 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After further research and a little help, I've figured out how to search by externalId.  Hopefully this is useful for someone in the future:

Using php:
Create a new GetRequest() object and a new RecordRef() object
set the RecordRef's externalId to the desired external ID
set the RecordRef's type to "vendor"
set the GetRequest's baseRef to the RecordRef you've just created
using the NetSuite client execute the get() method passing the the GetRequest() object created previously. The get() method will return a GetResponse() containing information about your search (and the object if it exists).

```
$getRequest = new \NetSuite\WebServices\GetRequest();
$recordRef = new \NetSuite\WebServices\RecordRef();
$recordRef->externalId = "theExternalIdGoesHere";
$recordRef->type = "vendor";
$getRequest->baseRef = $recordRef;
$response = $client->get($getRequest);
```

Comment: I am using this same code in 2016.1 version of the API, but I get an error status, with the statusDetail saying "INVALID_KEY_OR_REF" ("The specified key is invalid.").

Any thoughts?

My externalId provided is a GUID string, well under the 255 char limit for externalIds.

Answer (score 3):

Using Restlet

```
var vendorFilter = [];
vendorFilter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('externalid',null,'is',dataIn.externalid);


var vendorList = nlapiSearchRecord('vendor',null,vendorFilter,null);

var record = (vendorList!=null) ? nlapiLoadRecord('vendor',vendorList[0].getId()) : nlapiCreateRecord('vendor');

// process your logic
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  It throws:  error code: SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER
error message:An nlobjSearchFilter contains invalid search criteria: externalid.
What am I missing?  I know ExternalID is considered an 'attribute' instead of a 'field' but the docs say almost nothing else of ExternalID.

Comment: @RonNewcomb Me too. I get: {"error" : {"code" : "SSS_INVALID_SRCH_OPERATOR", "message" : "An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: externalid."}}

Comment: My problem was that my parameter was called externalId but I was using dataIn.externalid. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's snippet for c#: (I have used array of externalId, just in case if you want more than one)

### 1. Create multiselectfield search

```cs
SearchMultiSelectField field =
new SearchMultiSelectField
{
    @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true
};

var itemList = new List<com.netsuite.webservices.RecordRef>();
foreach (var externalId in externalIds)
{
    var recRef = new com.netsuite.webservices.RecordRef
    {
        externalId = externalId
    };
    itemList.Add(recRef);
}           

field.searchValue = itemList.ToArray();

var basic = new TransactionSearchBasic {externalId = field};
```

### 2. Call search function on service:

```cs
NetSuiteService service; // Instantiate with netsuite creds
SearchResult results = service.search(selectSearch);

List<Record> transactions = new List<Record>();

if (results?.status?.isSuccess ?? false)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= results.totalPages; i++)
    {
        var recordList = results.recordList;
        transactions.AddRange(recordList);
    }
}
else if (results?.status != null)
{
    this.log.Debug(GetStatusDetails(results.status));
}
else
{
    this.log.Debug("Failed to recieve results");
}

return transactions;
```

Answer (score 0):

The restlet code from user5227543 worked for me, except I had to add a check for vendorList.length>0 in addition to the null check:

> var record = (vendorList!=null && vendorList.length > 0) ? nlapiLoadRecord('vendor',vendorList[0].getId()) : nlapiCreateRecord('vendor');